# How to use Subnet as angular routing path

Tags: angular, ip, angular2-routing

Upon clicking I want to navigate to a particular path using angular2 but the path is Subnet (ex: xxx.xxx.5.0/26). As subnet as /26, I am not able to navigate to that particular route, is there any way we can solve this issue so that xxx.xxx.5.0/26 could be used as one string and I can navigate to this route

```
      <a  routerLink="/item/myips/xxx.xxx.5.0/26">xxx.xxx.5.0/26</a>
```

routing.module.ts

```
       import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

       const routes: Routes = [

          {
          path: 'item/myips/:id',
           component: InventoryComponent
           }]
       @NgModule({
         imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
        exports: [RouterModule]
         })
       export class RoutingModule {
        }
```

Is there any way we can make xxx.xxx.5.0/26 as one element instead of xxx.xxx.5.0 and /26 as angular is considering /26 as another route.

Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'item/myips/xxx.xxx.5.0/26'

Answer (score 0):

solved by using one more id in route where subnet mask 26 is another route

```
      const routes: Routes = [

      {
      path: 'item/myips/:id/:id',
       component: InventoryComponent
      }]
```

But I am still curious if we could route to xxx.xxx.5.0/26 considering as one string with / included.